# How to use pandas .agg() with dynamic column names and multiple functions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been playing around with pandas in order to get more familiar. I can't find a way to use `.pivot_table()` or `.agg()` with dynamic column names (`sticker_name`) and different functions (`list` for `book_sticker_id` and `'||.join` for `sticker_value`). I can't figure out how to replace `X` with `[COL_NAME]_book_sticker_ids` and `Y` with `[COL_NAME]_sticker_values` for each group in `sticker_name` column. Any help would be much appreciated!

**INPUT**

```
| book_id  | book_sticker_id   | sticker_name  | sticker_value  |
| -------- | ----------------- | ------------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 1                 | label         | Value 1        |
| 1        | 2                 | label         | Value 2        |
| 1        | 3                 | label         | Value 3        |
| 1        | 4                 | label2        | Value 4        |
| 1        | 5                 | label2        | Value 5        |
| 1        | 6                 | label2        | Value 6        |
| 2        | 7                 | label         | Value 7        |
| 2        | 8                 | label         | Value 8        |
| 2        | 9                 | label         | Value 9        |
| 2        | 10                | label2        | Value 10       |
| 2        | 11                | label2        | Value 11       |
| 2        | 12                | label2        | Value 12       |
and so on...
```

**MY ATTEMPT**

```
df = df.groupby('book_sticker_id').agg(X=('book_sticker_id', list), Y=('sticker_value', '||'.join))
```

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

```
| book_id  | label_book_sticker_ids  | label_sticker_values         | label2_book_sticker_ids | label2_sticker_values           |
|----------|-------------------------|------------------------------|-------------------------|---------------------------------|
| 1        | [1,2,3]                 | 'Value 1||Value 2||Value 3'  | [4,5,6]                 | 'Value 4||Value 5||Value 6'     |
| 2        | [7,8,9]                 | 'Value 7||Value 8||Value 9'  | [10,11,12]              | 'Value 10||Value 11||Value 12'  |

and so on...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
out = (df.groupby(['book_id','sticker_name'])
   .agg({'book_sticker_id':list,
        'sticker_value':'||'.join})
   .unstack()
   .sort_index(level=(1,0), axis=1)
)

out.columns = [f'{y}_{x}' for x,y in out.columns]
```

Output:

```
        label_book_sticker_id        label_sticker_value label2_book_sticker_id          label2_sticker_value
book_id                                                                                                      
1                   [1, 2, 3]  Value 1||Value 2||Value 3              [4, 5, 6]     Value 4||Value 5||Value 6
2                   [7, 8, 9]  Value 7||Value 8||Value 9           [10, 11, 12]  Value 10||Value 11||Value 12
```

Comment: Will need some time to understand what's happening, but it seems to work :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I made a mistake in my examples: I would like to have a single string for the values separated by '||'. Is there an easy way to make this happen with your code? `['Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3']` should become a single string with `Value 1||Value 2||Value 3`.

Comment: @konichiwa just use the `agg` with dictionary like you originally tried. See updated answer.